# Update (reload?) a JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, japplet, jeditorpane

I have `MyApplet` extending `JApplet` with a `JEditorPane centralPane`.

```
package view;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import controller.Manager;


public class MyApplet extends JApplet implements View {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JEditorPane centralPane;

    /**
     * @throws HeadlessException
     */
    public MyApplet() throws HeadlessException {
        centralPane = new JEditorPane();
    }



    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.applet.Applet#init()
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        super.init();
        add(centralPane);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see vue.Vue#fillPane(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void fillPane(String s) {
            centralPane.setText(s);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("test");
        View v = null;
        v = new myApplet();
        Manager.getManager().link(v);
    }
}
```

But when I call fillPane, nothing happen...
(fillPane is called by `Manager` and I tried to Run As a Java Application to check the content of `centralPane` and there's my `String`... But not if I Run As a Java Applet !
I tried `repaint()` or `revalidate()` and nothing works...

Comment: JEditorPane::setText refreshes just fine for me. Please provide more code.

Comment: I tried again running your code with the AppletViewer. Since I don't have the Manager class I used a Swing timer to call fillPane and the text was refreshed. I had MyApplet implement ActionListener. The AL just calls fillPane(). Then I used a timer in the constructor to call the AL -> Timer timer = new Timer(1, this); timer.setInitialDelay(2000); timer.start(); What does the Manager do ? Could you run your applet with the AppletViewer instead of this main method and test is separately ?

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Don't use an applet constructor (which might be called off the EDT. 3) Don't try to set the size of an applet, that is done in the HTML.